# I get the error that I must add return statement although I have added the return statement

Tags: java

```
public static ArrayList<Double> readSheet(XSSFSheet spreadsheet) {
    int rows = spreadsheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        
    for (int i = 0; i <= i; i++) {
        XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.getRow(i);
        
        if (row == null) {
            continue;
        }
        
        int cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        ArrayList<Double> cellList = new ArrayList<>();
    
        for (int j = 0; j < cells; j++) { //遍历每一列
            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
            cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                
            //new Double("1.0").intValue()
            Double cellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
            cellList.add(cellValue);        
        }
            
        return cellList;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help

Comment: infact here is other part

Comment: String FilePath = "D:\\student.xlsx";
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


    ArrayList<Double> xco1 = readSheet(spreadsheet );
    
    double [] ForceMy = new double[xco1.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < xco1.size(); i++)
     ForceMy[i] = xco1.get(i);
    
    for (Double F : ForceMy)
     System.out.print(F + " ");
    System.out.println("ForceMy.length = " + ForceMy.length);

Comment: Please edit your post with the code instead of putting it into the comments.

Comment: Did you *intend* to write `i <= i`? That is a weird way of writing a `while` loop.

Comment: (1) Think about the condition of your the first `for` loop. When will it terminate if the halt condition is `i <= i`? (2) the `return` statement is inside this loop, but there's a `continue` inside, too and (3) think about what might happen if `i` becomes a number whose corresponding row number does not exist in the sheet.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide the return statement outside of your for loop:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> readSheet(XSSFSheet spreadsheet) {
    int rows = spreadsheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    
    ArrayList<Double> cellList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= i; i++) {
        ...
    }
    return cellList;
}
```

Because the compile cannot decide if there is any run of your for loop and therefore not guarantee that your return statement will be reached.

This also means that you need to declare your `cellList` variable outside of the for loop.

And please also check your loop condition. While `i<=i` might be always `true` you don't want to loop indefinitely.

Comment: But `cellList` is not available outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your condition in `for` loop is wrong: `i <= i` is always `true`. 
Secondly, you must provide return statement for all branches. For example, if condition in `for` loop will be `false`, there is no `return` statements in remaining function body.

You should:

- put `cellList` before `for` loop
- put `return` statement outside `for` loop